# c++ vector performance non intuitive result?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio-2010

I am fiddling with the performance wizard in VS2010, the one that tests instrumentation (function call counts and timing.)

After learning about vectors in the C++ STL, I just decided to see what info I can get about performance of filling a vector with 1 million integers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void generate_ints();

int main() {
  generate_ints();
  return 0;
}

void generate_ints() {
  typedef std::vector<int> Generator;
  typedef std::vector<int>::iterator iter;
  typedef std::vector<int>::size_type size;

  Generator generator;

  for (size i = 0; i != 1000000; ++i) {
    generator.push_back(i);
  }
}
```

What I get is: 2402.37 milliseconds of elapsed time for the above. But I learnt that vectors have to resize themselves when they run out of capacity as they are contiguous in memory. So I thought I'd get better performance by making one addition to the above which was:

```
generate.reserve(1000000);
```

However this doubles the execution time of the program to around 5000 milliseconds. Here is a screenshot of function calls, left side without the above line of code and right side with. I really don't understand this result and it doesn't make sense to me given what I learnt about how defining a vectors capacity if you know you will fill it with a ton is a good thing. Specifying reserve basically doubled most of the function calls.

http://imagebin.org/179302

Comment: Am also wondering what this _RTC_CheckESP is which is always the most often called function.

Comment: How do you compile the code? Which compiler, and with or without optimizations?

Comment: I just freshly installed a trial of visual studio ultimate 2010, haven't done any optimization as i haven't learnt how. So i just press the green button basically. Clicking on performance wizard does this for me.

Comment: For _RTC_CheckESP see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914750/hows-rtc-checkesp-implemented

Comment: I see. In the menu bar there's a dropdown (right next to the green "run" button) which probably has `Debug` selected. Change that to `Release` and recompile. Then the compiler will enable optimizations. :)

Comment: Just so we're not overlooking the totally obvious here...you are adding the `reserve` line before (read: outside) the loop, right?

Comment: @cHao: This shouldn't matter. It doesn't reallocate memory when capacity is already greater than or equal to the requested.

Comment: Added it before the loop. I see it is in debug mode.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: it matters in that you get a million more function calls and a million more comparisons of capacity vs desired capacity. Even if they return immediately, they're likely to skew the result somewhat :)

Comment: @Cat: It might not reallocate, but it would always check the capacity.  Particularly in debug mode, that could mean making an extra function call or two every iteration.  Not that it matters, though, as apparently that's not the issue anyway.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the screenshot you posted, it looks like you're compiling without optimization, which invalidates any benchmarking you do.

You benchmark when you care about performance, and when you care about performance, you press the "go faster" button on the compiler, and enable optimizations.

Telling the compiler to go slow, and then worrying that it's slower than expected is pointless. I'm not sure why the code becomes *slower* when you insert a `reserve` call, but in debug builds, a lot of runtime checks are inserted to catch more errors, and it is quite possible that the `reserve` call causes more such checks to be performed, slowing down the code.

Enable optimizations and see what happens. :)

Comment: And wow what a difference when i select release mode. Had to learn about that sometime i guess!

Comment: Of course, once you enable optimizations, you likely run into another problem, that all your code gets optimized out entirely. See something like [this](http://latedev.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/the-joy-of-benchmarks/) for an example of how to avoid that

Comment: But also interesting how it can fill a vector with a million ints and i don't see any function that is called more than 35 times. I expected a million calls each time adding an int but its not what i see happening.

Comment: That's because all the function calls get inlined. When a number of conditions are satisfied (the compiler can see the called function's body, and the body is sufficiently small, and the call occurs sufficiently often), the compiler can basically copy the function body into the call-site, replacing the actual function call. It can be a very powerful optimization (and when used in the wrong places, it can harm performance)

Comment: @DanielGratz So did you get expected results when you tested under Release configuration? I was quite puzzled why Debug would "reverse" the elapsed time instead of just generally slowing it down, so I tested your code and on my machine it produced "correct" results on both Debug and Release configurations (`reserve` was faster in both cases). Note that I used `clock` to measure time and ran outside of both debugger and profiler - this might be an indication that you are not seeing effects of different build configurations but of profiler or even debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Did you perform all your benchmarks under Release configuration?

Also, try running outside of profiler, in case you have hit some profiler-induced artifact (add manual time measurements to your code - you can use `clock()` for that).

Also, did you by any chance make a typo and actually called `resize` instead of `reserve`?