# The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call. mixing stdcall and cdecl

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012, calling-convention

The stack trace from WinDBG:

```
OpenCL!failwithmessage+0x1dd (FPO: [Non-Fpo]) (CONV: cdecl)
OpenCL!_RTC_Failure+0x29 (FPO: [Non-Fpo]) (CONV: cdecl)
OpenCL!_RTC_CheckEsp+0x19 (FPO: [Non-Fpo]) (CONV: cdecl)
OpenCL!CommandNDRange::execute+0xa4 (FPO: [Non-Fpo]) (CONV: thiscall)
OpenCL!Context::run_commands+0x172 (FPO: [Non-Fpo]) (CONV: thiscall)
OpenCL!process_commands+0x2a (FPO: [Non-Fpo]) (CONV: cdecl)
OpenCL!os_thread_launcher+0x46 (FPO: [Non-Fpo]) (CONV: stdcall)
KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x20 (FPO: [SEH])
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
```

I guess the problem is caused by different calling conventions of os_thread_launcher and process_commands, correct?

**os_thread_launcher** is from a static library and declared with '*extern*'. it's the thread function used by CreateThread. process_commands is called inside os_thread_launcher.

I cannot change the calling convention of **process_commands** to *__stdcall* because it's signature has to be

```
void (*osthreadfunc_t)(void*)
```

as required by the Windows API **CreateThread**

Comment: That is not the correct signature for a thread function passed to `CreateThread`. The correct signature can be found in the documentation. However, `OpenCL!os_thread_launcher` would appear to be the thread function. It's the highest function in the call stack that is not in a system DLL. I would expect the problem to be at the bottom of the call stack. Also, what is your question?

Comment: @David, my question is how to solve this issue. Thx

Comment: First step is to work out which function is the problem. Then look at some code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with OpenCL, but Microsoft's `RTC_CheckEsp` routine will signal a failure *after* a problem with calling convention mismatch has been detected. So, I would bet that `CommandNDRange::execute` is calling some (user-supplied?) function/method that is using an incorrect calling convention, or otherwise mangling the stack.

Because control has not yet returned from any other functions on the stack (or they wouldn't BE on the stack!), this is unlikely a problem with any of them.

Comment: only member functions (of the same class as execute) are called in execute.

Comment: The implementation http://stackoverflow.com/a/3914866/925478 of RTC_CheckESP is pretty straightforward, and it looks like the only explanation is that one of the functions/methods called by `execute` is mangling the stack. Keep in mind it might be a function called from more than one level deep...If you can post relevant code snippets that would certainly help.